# ORACLE TRIGGER update table if another one is updated

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to change a field in all rows of a table when updating another one.
I have a game table, a referee table (with an nation_id) and the nation table.
 Now I want to auto update the referee_nation_Name from the game table if someone update the nation_id in the referee table. 
My problem is i have no idea how to get the referee_id (which is unique) when someone update the nation_id in this table. If i select all referee_id which are like :new.nation_id i will get the other referee ids from peoples who life in this country... here is my non working trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER name
AFTER UPDATE OF nation_id ON referee
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    nationname VARCHAR2(150);
BEGIN
    SELECT n.name INTO nationname
            FROM nation n, referee r, game g
      WHERE n.nation_id = r.nation_id AND g.referee_id = :old.referee_id);
    UPDATE game SET referee_nation_Name = nationname WHERE referee_id = :old.referee_id;
END;
```

Comment: Why are you storing the name of the nation in the `referee` table in the first place?  Your data model should be properly normalized.  So you shouldn't be storing the name of the referee's nation if you already have a reference to the `nation` table where that is already stored.

Comment: i know but it is for school. so i have to do it... ^^

Comment: You are missing a join condition in your select statement (wouldn't happen if you used an explicit `JOIN`)

Comment: whoops you are right. but it doesnt solve the problem. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that you would never design a data model that stored denormalized data like this precisely because it is incredibly hard to keep in sync, your instructor is probably looking for something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER name
  BEFORE UPDATE OF nation_id ON referee
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    l_nationname VARCHAR2(150);
BEGIN
    SELECT name
      INTO l_nationname 
      FROM nation
     WHERE nation_id = :new.nation_id;

    UPDATE game
       SET referee_nation_name = l_nationname
     WHERE referee_id = :new.referee_id;
END;
```

Of course, this doesn't address what happens when someone updates the `nation` table to change the `name` among other possible holes.

Comment: thanks that worked but i just saw that my update statement wasnt complete here. So i still need the refree_id if i want to only update the right referee_nation_Name in the game table.

Comment: @user1069968 - Sorry, I thought you were saying that `referee_nation_name` was in the `referee` table not in the `game` table.  Updated my answer.  FYI, it's always helpful if you post the DDL to create your objects and some sample data so that we can test our answers.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER name
BEFORE UPDATE OF nation_id ON referee
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
l_nationname VARCHAR2(150);
BEGIN
SELECT name
INTO l_nationname
FROM nation
WHERE nation_id = :new.nation_id;

```
UPDATE game
   SET referee_nation_name = l_nationname
 WHERE referee_id = :new.referee_id;
```

END;